# Intervention Image source not readable on update

Tags: image, laravel, intervention, laravel-5.5

I have searched, and did not find an answer to this problem.

Well, i am using intervention with laravel 5.5 to upload photos. 
When i `create` a new recipe(in my case), all is working and the photos are being uploaded succefully.

This is the code for the initial upload:

```
$front_image = $request->file('front_image');

$frontImageName = md5(time()) . '.' . $front_image
                    ->getClientOriginalExtension();

$locationfi = public_path('photos/front/' . $frontImageName);

Image::make($front_image)
    ->resize(454,340)
    ->insert(public_path('photos/logo.png'),'bottom-right')
    ->save($locationfi);

$recipe->front = $frontImageName;
```

All standard stuff. 
But when i try to `edit` a recipe, i get `Image source not readable`.
This is the code for the re upload:

```
        $front_image = $request->file('front_image');

        $frontImageName = md5(time()).'.'.$front_image
                      ->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $location = public_path('photos/front/'.$frontImageName );

        Image::make($front_image)->resize(690,517)
            ->insert(public_path('photos/tk.png'),'bottom-right')
        ->save($location);

        //update the database
        $recipe->front=$imageName;
```

I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in both forms, for create and update.
On the update form i also use `{{method_field('PUT'}}`.

What am i missing here? Thanks.

Comment: which version of php are you using ?

Comment: I am using php 7. @sunitiyadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. "It is always to little things", so they say.
When i inserted the logo image, i refered to a phtoto that does not exists. Thats why it gave me the error, obviously.